# Is it possible to change the default Release build configuration properties in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

When a new C# project is created, two build configurations are added to the respective csproj file - Debug and Release.

My problem is that the Release build configuration does not include the full debug information by default. I know the default is reasonable for the Release build, but in my particular case I want to change it to full debug info.

Is it possible to tweak the Visual Studio 2012 in such a way that new projects have their Release build with full debug info?

Answer (score 1):

There is a *very ugly* way to do it:

The default project templates are stored in `$(VSINSTALLDIR)\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\CSharp\Windows\1033\` and you can modify them, with appropriate administrator permissions, to include whatever you'd like. This includes modifying the defaults for the debug configuration to remove the `DEBUG` define and to set the 'optimize' flag.

Note that making this kind of modification is *global* and will affect all new projects for all users on the machine. It's probably not a great idea, and I'd strongly suggest just remembering to adjust the properties of new projects as you need to, or to [create a custom template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6db0hwky%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

It's ugly, but it seems to work fine in my cursory tests.

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution for C++ projects, however I am afraid it is not applicable to C#:

Use a Property Manager (View / Property Manager). You can edit a property sheet called Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.user. This property sheet is used by all projects (both Debug and Release configurations). If you set your debugging requirements there, you will do no harm do Debug, as it already includes it anyway and cause Release to include it as you want.

Comment: You are correct, I need it for C#, so C++ does not help me much.